# Why is IntSet lookup O(min(n,W)), and not O(1)?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, integer, set, lookup

According to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html, the `member` function, which looks up whether an int is in the `IntSet`, takes O(min(n,W)) time, where `n` is the number of elements in the `IntSet`, and W = 32 on a 32-bit machine and 64 on a 64-bit machine.

I imagine that in practice, W is probably less than n, so the function would be O(W) time.

In practice (on a fixed architecture), O(W) is constant, and so this function probably runs very fast (or at least doesn't get slower as a function of n).

However, in theory, this isn't that fast. If we allow integers a₁,...,aₙ of unbounded size (and let `W = log a`, where `a = maxₚ aₚ`, then this function runs in O(log a). Why can't we use hashing and achieve O(1) amortized cost for this function?

(Context: I'm working on an algorithms homework assignment, and for part of my pseudocode for a problem, I desire a data structure that can check if an integer is a member of my set in constant time, regardless of the number of integers in the set, or the size of the integers in the set. I tried looking up Haskell `Set`-like data structures for inspiration.)

Comment: It'll be hard to make a good hash function if you don't even look at the whole integer which will take $O(lg a)$ time.

Comment: You can't even *compare* your input integer to a single integer from your set in constant time if you're actually considering the log(n) factors of unbounded integers.

Comment: The famous O(1) amortized hashing time is achieve quite simply: let's assume that computing the hash of an element takes O(1) time then... If you drop the O(1) hashing time assumption you no longer have O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DerekElkins said in the comments, just reading a single unbounded-size integer takes a minimum of O(log a) time.  As a result, it's not possible in any sense to do better.

If you don't have fixed-size primitives, essentially nothing is O(1).